# Rails 3: Search method returns all models instead of specified

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, methods

**What I'm trying to do:** I have a model "Recipe" in which I defined a method "search" that takes an array of strings from checkboxes (I call them tags), and a single string. The idea is to search the db for recipes that has anything in it's 'name' or 'instructions' that contains the string, AND also has any of the tags matching it's 'tags' property.

**Problem:** The search method return all the recipes in my db, and doesn't seem to work at all at finding by the specific parameters.

The action method in the controller:

```
def index
      @recipes = Recipe.search(params[:search], params[:tag])
      if !@recipes
        @recipes = Recipe.all
      end
      respond_to do |format|
      format.html 
      format.json { render json: @recipe }
    end
  end
```

The search method in my model:

```
  def self.search(search, tags)
    conditions = ""

    search.present? do
        # Condition 1: recipe.name OR instruction same as search?
        conditions = "name LIKE ? OR instructions LIKE ?, '%#{search[0].strip}%', '%#{search[0].strip}%'"

     # Condition 2: if tags included, any matching?
      if !tags.empty?
        tags.each do |tag|
          conditions += "'AND tags LIKE ?', '%#{tag}%'"
        end
      end
      end
    # Hämtar och returnerar alla recipes där codition 1 och/eller 2 stämmer.
        Recipe.find(:all, :conditions => [conditions]) unless conditions.length < 1
  end
```

Any ideas why it return all records?

Comment: Yes, that's absolutely true. If you have a better example, please enlighten me. This is what I have come up with so far.

Comment: How are your tags being returned in the params? As an array or as a string? You might have to run `split()` on them first if they're just a string.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's an array of strings like ["meat", "fish"].

Answer (score 0):

if you are using rails 3, then it is easy to chain find conditions

```
def self.search(string, tags)
  klass = scoped

  if string.present?
    klass = klass.where('name LIKE ? OR instructions LIKE ?', "%#{string}%", "%#{string}%")
  end

  if tags.present?
    tags.each do |tag|
      klass = klass.where('tags LIKE ?', "%#{tag}%")
    end
  end

  klass
end
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
search.present? do
  ...
end
```

The contents of that block are ignored - it's perfectly legal to pass a block to a function that doesn't expect one, however the block won't get called unless the functions decides to. As a result, none of your condition building code is executed. You probably meant

```
if search.present?
  ...
end
```

As jvnill points out, it is in general much nicer (and safer) to manipulate scopes than to build up SQL fragments by hand

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know much about the block behaviors. I probably need to rethink this whole thing a little. jvnills way looks good, except I need the tags to be a must 'where' statement if they are present. Any ways, thanks.